# Has the Facebook login mechanism changed?

Tags: support, login, facebook

I've update my browser to Chrome 65 and it logged me out from sites (maybe because I ran git-bomb from incognito mode before I restarted the browser). I can no longer login to Stack Overflow using Facebook. I needed to set my password using email.

Has Stack Exchange changed the way it logs-in users, because the layout changed (navigation on the left).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with it? Are you getting errors?

Comment: @animuson it ask me to confirm to give access to SO and process with name Jakub so I thought that it would create account with username Jakub not use my old jcubic. AFAIK facebook ask for permission only once.